# Multiple form execution in Struts 2

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, web-applications, struts2

I am working on Struts 2 and Hibernate integration application where I have to make employee registration system like

1. Employee name details JSP page
2. Employee education detail page.
3. Employee qualification detail

I am putting these pages on each others success page so that successfully registration of on page show the form of other page but after entering the value in first page it running success fully and showing second page which is Education details but when i am putting value and submitting it. It does not work and  I am getting  the error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity
    org.hibernate.event.spi.SaveOrUpdateEvent.<init>(SaveOrUpdateEvent.java:62)
    org.hibernate.event.spi.SaveOrUpdateEvent.<init>(SaveOrUpdateEvent.java:45)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:748)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:744)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    $Proxy13.save(Unknown Source)
    dao.Edudao.add(Edudao.java:13)
    action.Eduaction.execute(Eduaction.java:24)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
           <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true"/>
           <constant name="struts.devmode" value="true"/>
         
          <package name="loginmodel" extends ="struts-default">
             <action name ="employee" class ="action.Empaction">
             <result name = "input">/EMP/employee.jsp</result>
             <result name ="success">/EMP/empedu.jsp</result>
            </action>
            <action name ="education" class="action.Eduaction">
             <result name= "siccess">/EMP/success.jsp</result>
                     
            </action>
                                  
         </package>
</struts>
```

I am using Hibernate in DAO layer

**`Edudao.java`:**

```
package dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import model.Empedu;

public class Edudao {
public Empedu  add(Empedu model){
     Session session1 = ConnectionFactory.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    
    
     session1.beginTransaction();
     session1.save(model);
     
     session1.getTransaction().commit();
       return model;

}
    
}
```

**`Eduaction.class` is:**

```
package action;

import model.Empedu;


import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

import dao.Edudao;

    public class Eduaction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Empedu> {
     
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Empedu model;
    
        public Empedu getModelobj() {
        return model;
    }
    public void setModelobj(Empedu model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String execute()throws Exception{
        Edudao edudao = new Edudao();
        Empedu queryresult = edudao.add(getModelobj());
        if(queryresult!=null){
            return SUCCESS;
            }
        else
            return ERROR;
    }       
        @Override
        public Empedu getModel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: can you please share your action class and jsps code to check whats the flow and where could be issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Edudao.add()` you should not use `saveOrUpdate` on `null` or transient instance of the entity. Use `save` method to persist the transient instance.

Change the code to

```
public Empedu add(Empedu model) throws Exception {
  if (model == null || model.getId() != null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("null model, or has id not null");

  Session session = ConnectionFactory.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

  try {
    session.save(model);

    tx.commit();
    return model;
  } finally{
    if (session.isOpen()){
      try {
        ConnectionFactory.getSessionFactory().closeSession();
      }
     catch (Exception e2) {}
   }
 }
}
```